# How to convert os.system command to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

I need run following comamnd in background on windows machine(windows 7)

```
os.system("SET TZ=GMT-5 && firefox")
```

Seems like I should use `Popen`, but command

```
subprocess.Popen("SET TZ=GMT-5;firefox", shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

has no effect. Other variant `os.spawnl` causes errors since i use rpc.

Any idea how to run `os.system("SET TZ=GMT-2 && firefox")` in bg?

**SOLUTION 1**

Add `start` in front of *.exe command

```
os.system("SET TZ=GMT-5 && start firefox")
```

Comment: See `env` argument of `Popen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already hinted in comments, you can pass an `env` parameter to `Popen` and friends to modify the environment of the program you are starting.

I'm guessing you *actually* want `subprocess.run()` instead, but this obviously depends on what exactly you need to do with the process once you have started it.

```
subprocess.run(['firefox'], env={'TZ': 'GMT-5'})
```

As remarked in comments, you probably want to pass all of `os.environ` with your addition.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['TZ'] = 'GMT-5'
subprocess.run(['firefox'], env=env)
```

If your change is harmless, you might manipulate `os.environ` directly, of course.

Comment: You need to pass the whole environment to `env`, so I suggest including everything in `os.environ` otherwise some things are likely to break.

Comment: But then you might as well manipulate `os.environ` directly.  Thanks for the pointer, though.